# z-index and background-image problems

Tags: html, css

I have a text on top of a background-image and that text needs to be z-index -1.
But when I do that the text goes underneath the background image.
So you cant see the text anymore. Is there a way to give a z-index to a background-image. if not is there a other way to see the text above the background-image while it is z-index -1.

Thank you if you can help me :)

### html

```
<div class="text">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</div>
<div class="test">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .test {
    height:9000px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:50px;
    z-index:10;
}

    h1 {
        position:fixed;
        margin-top:-50px;
        z-index:1;
    }
```

EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/6pjmw7wv/
In the jsfiddle I got a example when you scroll down the text need to go underneath the red color but how?

EDIT2: https://jsfiddle.net/06ht2fp8/
This is a better example if you still dont understand it the text needs to stay above the blue but go underneath the red.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The only way to achieve this is by making the div have z-index -1. Why you make the text have z-index:-1? If you want to toggle visibility you can use the display attribute

Comment: Why does the text need to be `z-index:-1`..and the text isn't under the image..it's under the parent wrapper...which is not quite the same.

Comment: @JmRag I make it like that so when I scroll down it looks like the div underneath it scrolls over the image and the text and it doesnt look like I am scrolling down.

Comment: I will add a jsfiddle to make it more clear what I am trying to do

Comment: You mean you want a static background?

Comment: @JmRag No like the text is `position:fixed` and the background color red is like the content of the website so if you scroll down the text needs to go underneath the content/red background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct what you want you can change the z-index of the h1 to -1:

https://jsfiddle.net/gt9z8svL/

```
.test {
    height:9000px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:50px;
    z-index:10;
}

h1 {
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:-50px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

---

the answer for your fiddle in the comments:
https://jsfiddle.net/d0b2Ldue/

just add `position:relative;` and `z-index:10` at the class of the div

```
.test1 {
    height:9000px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: ye that is what I mean but on the real site there is a background color behind the text so if I give it -1 it also goes behind that one

Comment: I don't quite understand what goes behind what . Can you give a better example in fiddle or a better more complete description?

Comment: I am going to try to make a better example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/06ht2fp8/ I got a better example the text needs to stay above the blue color but go underneath the red color but when you give it a z-index:-1 it also goes underneath the blue color

Answer (score 0):

This might help you-

```
<div class='image-container'>
<span> Text Over Image </span>
</div>


.image-container
{
  background-image:url("http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/30800000/-Random-random-30843840-1920-1080.jpg");
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
}

span
{
  font-size:25px;
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

**JsFiddle-**
https://jsfiddle.net/codecore/d4s6yktf/1/

Comment: I dont want the text over the image but behind it. let me explain it. You have a text above a image with position fixed so when you scroll down the text follows your screen but when it hits the background image it needs to go underneed that image you get it?